# MongoDB replicaSet config - strange behaviour

Tags: mongodb, replication, virtualbox

I'm trying to implement mongoDB replication, made up of 4 nodes in the form of Virtual Machines,

Info: I use virtualbox, and v.machines comunicate with each other throught the **host-only adapter**. Communication is been tested, and ervery node can ping other nodes.

this is the output of **rs.conf()** command :

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 4,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "192.168.56.1:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "192.168.56.101:27018"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "192.168.56.102:27019"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "host" : "192.168.56.103:27020"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the output of the command **rs.status()**

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-12-14T16:09:36Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "192.168.56.1:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 3207,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1387034904, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-12-14T15:28:24Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "192.168.56.101:27018",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 6,
            "stateStr" : "UNKNOWN",
            "uptime" : 2542,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-12-14T16:09:35Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "still initializing"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "192.168.56.102:27019",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 6,
            "stateStr" : "UNKNOWN",
            "uptime" : 2497,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-12-14T16:09:35Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "still initializing"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "192.168.56.103:27020",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 6,
            "stateStr" : "UNKNOWN",
            "uptime" : 2472,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-12-14T16:09:36Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "still initializing"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

from the last command it seems the replicaSet is still initializating, but looking at the 4 instances of mongod, i don't know, it seems like here is something not working properly..

[image]

im wondering why all the nodes try to contact only the primary instance ignoring the ohers? And why when the connection get accepted, it try again to contact the same node, failing to do that because it say that "Couldn't load config yet".. i really need a thrust for understand the problem, if is necessary any other command output, or information in general just let me know i'll post them.

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Although you have checked network connection with ping, have you tried to connect servers in both directions? I mean, you should be able to connect from one server to the shell of all other servers. Maybe your firewall is blocking connections.

Comment: If a node cannot see a primary then it is like constantly triggering an election. Without a primary the replica set isn't considered consistent. Every node needs to be registered with the currently primary and needs to be able to get information from that primary, even if it continues to sync from a secondary.

Comment: @rubenfa: you mean connecting to the istances in the way of "mongo --port 27019" , no i didn't tryied it, i thought pinging was enught, i ll try to check that way soon

Comment: @Sammaye. the primary node is the first one terminal, i think this replica set have a primary then. i didn't really understood what you trying to tell to me

Comment: You asked why the others try to only contact the primary first, ignoring all others

Comment: oh okay i got it, also you saying that the connection to the primary never happened? i beleave you right, it make sense, but why the secondary nodes keep returning "connection accepted from 192.168.56.1"

Comment: I am quite confused, you can see that the primary can communicate with its members it is like the host-only adapter is stopping member to primary communication, I use vmware but I dont get this problem, but then looking again I think I use NAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved** - i just checked the connections betweens all members in the way of mongo connection like rubenfa suggested in his comment.

```
mongo --host 192.168.56.103 --port 27020
```

and every connection between each members work properly using **Host-only** Adapter.

the main problem i posted at the beginning, was related to the fact that i didn't checked inside the 3 secondary nodes, if there was others `local` database created from the previous attempts to configure the replicaSet. I just used to check the primary node, and delete the local db from there, without check other nodes.

Also, remember to delete all the `local` dbs from all the nodes before try to reconfigure replicaSet

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling on this:

Make sure your primary's hostname is resolvable from the members, or otherwise your replSetConfig is using your primary's IP instead of hostname or fqdn.
By default mongo uses the primary's hostname in the "host" configuration field,
making all the other members fail to communicate with it if they don't have the information in the /etc/hosts file.